# COCA corpus: Is it possible to display a list search result as parts of speech?

Tags: corpora, parts-of-speech

I want to know what parts of speech (and in what frequency) follow a word or phrase.  If I do a list search, for example "for the purpose of *", the result is a list of the actual words in order of frequeny.  Is it possible to display the result as parts of speech instead?  That is, instead of showing "private" (494 instances), followed by "this" (397), "the" (137), "making" (93), etc., it shows 3000 nouns, 1000 verbs, 500 determiners, etc.

Thanks in advance.

NB.

(1) I know there is a KWIC search, which color-codes the results according to their parts of speech, but the results seem to be (1) random and (2) arranaged alphabetically (as opposed to frequency.)

(2) ChatGPT gave me conflicting results.  The first time, it told me to choose display as parts of speech from a dropdown menu in the results page, but I can't see such a choice in any dropdown menu.  Could it be that I'm using the unlicensed version?  The second time, it told me it was not possible.

Comment: I would recommend not asking ChatGPT for technical help, since as a general rule it doesn't actually know what it's talking about.